# Check location permissions with MVVM in Android?

Tags: android, mvvm, permissions

I need to request runtime location permissions for the **FusedLocationProviderClient** api and, once I have them, obtain Location objects and feed them to an algorithm that will make a query to an endpoint. The results of such a query will be used to update my map View.
As of now, I'm using **MVVM**, so I have an **Activity** showing the Map, and its **ViewModel** implementing **LiveData** objects to update the View, and a **Repository** class to perform network operations.
[image: MVVM by Android]

My doubts are essentially about where to ask for runtime permissions (I'm using *EasyPermissions* library). I know that I have to implement permission checks methods in the Activity, however I find myself at odds with how to proceed then: do I have to also implement a listener for location updates in the Activity? If so, how do I then send that data to the repo for the query (the View will then be updated with Observer pattern)? In a way, it would be more convenient for me to ask for permissions in the repo since that's where I'll immediately use the location objects.

Answer (score 1):

As you are dealing with location, you should probably use the Lifecycle library, main use case of this library is for your use-case only.

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/lifecycle

And for the Permissions I would ask in activity and use Observer pattern to send the location updates to the view model.